# Ruby-on-rails ransack gem filter builder config route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am reading code(written by someone else) that uses the ransack gem to build a filter. In the config file there is a route that is as follows:

get '/app_hosts/ransack_filter_builder' => 'app_hosts#ransack_filter_builder', :format => :js

I can't find a method called ransack_filter_builder anywhere. Application_helper has one called filterBuilder and application_controller has a filter_builder_controller. so, what is it(#ransack_filter_builder) referring to? Is it something created by rails?

Comment: Add the app_hosts controller.

Comment: Actually I forgot to mention that app_hosts doesn't have it. Neither does app_hosts_helper.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a gem in the Gemfile called ransack? If so, then this method comes from that gem.  [Here](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack) is the gem documentation.